# CSS Hover Effects with duration of mouse out

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS effect in below codepen. The hover works fine, on hover the image grows and when you mouse off it gradually decreases back to original size. I want to change the gradual decrease so that it is quicker, infact instant. So basically when I move mouse away, it immediately returns to original size.. can someone help?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="photo">
<img src="http://s.cdpn.io/37045/wedding-1.jpg" alt="" class="photo-image" /></div>
<div class="photo"><img src="http://s.cdpn.io/37045/wedding-2.jpg" alt="" class="photo-image" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.photo-image {
 cursor: pointer;
 position:relative;
 top:9px;
 left:9px;
 width:80px;
 border:1px solid #999; 
 z-index:1000;
 opacity:0.6;
 transition: width 1s, top 1s, left 1s, opacity 1s, z-index .01s;
}

.photo-image:hover{
 width:200px;
 top:-50px;
 left:-50px;
 z-index:1001;
 opacity:1;
}
```

Codepen example: http://codepen.io/DouglasGlover/pen/zHBid/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple! Just move the transition effect from `.photo-image` to .`photo-image:hover`:

```
.photo-image:hover {
 transition: width 1s, top 1s, left 1s, opacity 1s, z-index .01s;
}
```

Comment: I'll explain a bit more because I used to struggle with this: It might not be entirely logical to everyone, but the "target" state (i.e., the one the element is stepping INTO, is the one that gets the precedence in transition properties, and NOT the "source" state. It took me a while to grasp it, maybe I'm just an idiot

Comment: Thanks @casraf — your explanation is more useful than the here's-your-answer.